# What is known as Mocha

Tags: javascript

I am learning the JavaScript contents from this [site](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html). At first line, they mentioned as `JavaScript, aka Mocha`. What is the meaning of `Mocha` here.

Comment: Mocha is a feature-rich JavaScript test framework running on [node](http://nodejs.org/) and the browser, making asynchronous testing simple and fun. Mocha tests run serially, allowing for flexible and accurate reporting, while mapping uncaught exceptions to the correct test cases. Hosted on [GitHub](http://github.com/visionmedia/mocha). See [link](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)

Comment: @A.V interesting, but not what Crockford refers to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was developed under the name Mocha (by Netscape)

Linky: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Comment: Seconded. But note that Crockford wrote that a long time ago. It is currently and has not for some time been AKA "Mocha."

Answer (score 1):

They are simply referring to one of the many names that Javascript has been know as.

The official name for Javascript -i.e. the one that the standards community makes all their rules under, is [Ecmascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

As a note: as the other answer indicates it was developed under the name `Mocha` but that was never a name used for any distribution. The first distribution name was LiveScript, and was changed to Javascript soon after to basically take advantage of free publicity, with the rise in popularity of Java at the time.

Hence the name when it is in fact not related to java.

Answer (score 1):

raghavv@ provided the correct answer.

If you search for JavaScript and Mocha now you'll most likely encounter [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/): a JavaScript testing framework for [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) that goes by the same name.